# How do I resolve the following promises?

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, callback

I'm trying to resolve the promise in the getABC function, but the local const variable b returns undefined. How do I implement the callback function used by the getB function so that it returns the destructured array item with the value of 'B'.

```js
const [A, B, C] = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

function getA() {
  return A;
}

function getB(callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback(B);
  }, 10);
}

function getC() {
  return Promise.resolve().then(() => C);
}

function getABC() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const a = getA();
    const b = getB(b => b);
    const c = getC().then(item => item).catch(err => console.log(err));

    resolve([a, b, c])
  });
}

getABC().then((arr) => console.log(arr));
```

Comment: Your `getB` doesn't return anything. You just give it a callback that essentially does nothing. It just gets called 10 milliseconds later. Was it meant to actually resolve a promise 10ms later?

Comment: getB is meant to return global variable B.

Comment: `function getABC() { return Promise.all([getA(), new Promise(getB), getC()]); }` But really you should just change the implementation of `getB` to return a promise instead of accepting a callback.

Comment: The code is for a coding challenge, so I didn't write it.

Comment: @MoonShine - "_I'm trying to resolve the promise in_" & "_How do I implement the callback function_" - it _appears like_ you wrote it based on your question - regardless, Bergi answered the question you wrote very directly.

Comment: @MoonShine that's not at all what it does.

Comment: it does now! thanks, guys.

Answer (score 1):

You also have to wrap `setTimeout` inside a Promise, and call `Promise.all` before `resolve`:

```js
const [A, B, C] = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

function getA() {
  return A;
}

function getB(callback) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(callback(B));
    }, 10);
  });
}

function getC() {
  return Promise.resolve().then(() => C);
}

function getABC() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const a = getA();
    const b = getB(b => b);
    const c = getC().then(item => item).catch(err => console.log(err));

    resolve(Promise.all([a, b, c]));
  });
}

getABC().then(arr => console.log(arr));
```

All of these can truly be simplified if you use async/await.